# "Ad nauseum" vs "ad nauseam"

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference between the two: *ad nauseam* and *ad nauseum*?

Comment: Well... one is [in the dictionary](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=ad+nauseam&title=21st) and thus correct; and one isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is correct, Latin preposition *ad* takes the accusative (of *nausea*).

I have not encountered the second - it's probably incorrect, unless there is a neuter noun *nauseum*.